# Cunit test invalid read/write of size8

Tags: c

Invalid read and write of size 8 happening in ***modify_tab_size()***.

what am I doing wrong? Ive tried almost everything, I dont understand it.

```
// Function being tested.
int erase_repeated(int *nb_words, char **words) {
   for (int i = 0; i < *nb_words; ++i) {
      if (words[i] != 0) {
         for (int b = 0; b < *nb_words; ++b) {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[b]) == 0 && b != i)
               modify_tab_size(&b, nb_words, words);
         }
      }
   }
   return *nb_mots;
}

void modify_tab_size(int *b, int *nb_words_update, char **words) {
   free(words[*b]);
   for (int k = *b; k < *nb_words_update; k++) {
      words[k] = words[k + 1];         <--------------------------read error
      words[*nb_words_update + 1] = 0; <--------------------------write error
   }
   (*nb_words_update)--;
   (*b)--;
}
```

Comment: `free(words[i]);` and `const char *s = words[d]; *s`. Where have you allocated any of the `words[i]` pointers? It seems you are freeing and dereferencing NULL pointers (the former is ok but not the latter). Aren't you missing code that reads from the file into the `words`?

Comment: compile with -g so that valgrind can give you line numbers

Comment: @pm100 I found, also specified here, where the errors are happening. I still cant make sense of it. any idea or guess?

Comment: almost certainly the code you dont show - 'place_words_in_array' is wrong, please add it to the question

Comment: What does `place_words_in_array` do?

Comment: @pm100 added that function at the end.

Comment: @Schwern just added it at the end.

Comment: Is your intent to delete both instances of MATT?

Comment: @LIsa Do some more testing. You have an array of two elements, but one is blank. It's not enough to test just the length.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `k+1` and `*nb_words_update + 1` can walk off the array, and it is. Add `printf("k:%d, k+1:%d, *nb_words_update + 1: %d\n", k, k+1, *nb_words_update + 1);` into the loop to see.

```
k:1, k+1:2, *nb_words_update + 1: 4
k:2, k+1:3, *nb_words_update + 1: 4
```

You've only allocated three slots, 3 and 4 walk off the end of the array.

Since `nb_words_update` starts as the length of the array, `words[*nb_words_update + 1] = 0;` is always going to be too large. `words[*nb_words_update] = 0;` is also too large.

What you seem to be trying to do is deleting an element from an array by shifting everything after it to the left.

```
void delete_element(char **words, int *b, int *size) {
    // Free the string to be deleted.
    free(words[*b]);

    // Only go up to the second to last element to avoid walking off the array.
    for (int i = *b; i < *size-1; i++) {
        // Shift everything to the left.
        words[i] = words[i+1];
    }

    // Null out the last element.
    // Don't use 0 for NULL, it's confusing.
    words[*size-1] = NULL;

    // Decrement the size of the array.
    (*size)--;

    // Redo the check with the newly shifted element.
    (*b)--;
}
```

This sort of thing is better done with a linked list.

---

Note that your code has a bug. The result is an array of two elements, but one of them is blank. In addition to the return value of `erase_repeated`, also test its side effect which is to modify `words`. Test that `words` contains what you think it does.

Comment: thats what I see indeed. I misread what you said before. its only supposed to delete one instance of a repeated word. So I should be left with only two words, MATT and MIMMIE. Im freeing that spot in the first line in modify_tab_size(), shouldnt that fix that problem?

Comment: @LIsa `free(words[*b]);` just frees the memory for the string `MATT`. You have off-by-one errors in how you're shifting the words around. I've added more details and a corrected function.